# Websphere 9.0.0 not able to connect Db2 database from WAS admin in Linux

Tags: java, db2, websphere

**It was working from last 3 month but from last 3 days I am facing this issue**
Even After creating JNDI in Websphere when I try to connect test connection it giving me the following error.

```
 java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: null DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = -1,639
```

I am not able to restart node agent it gives me the following error with ./startNode.sh and ./stopNode.sh

serverNode01/servers/nodeagent/server.xml file is missing

Please give an idea to restart the node agent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of [SQL1639N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic5.html#sql1639n):

> **SQL1639N**   The database server was unable to perform authentication
>   because security-related database manager files on the server do not
>   have the required operating system permissions.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> The DB2 database system requires that your instance and database
>   directories, and the files in those directories, have a minimum level
>   of operating system permissions. When the instance and database
>   directories are created by the database manager the permissions are
>   accurate, and changing those permissions could cause database manager
>   functions to fail. The complexity of DB2 file permissions is increased
>   in the case of non-root installed instances and operating system-based
>   authentication.
>
> This message is returned when security-related database manager
>   executable files do not have necessary permissions for the database
>   manager to perform remote connection authentication-related tasks.
>
> There are several reasons why these security-related files might not
>   have the necessary permissions, including the following reasons:
>
> The database manager instance is a non-root installed instance and operating system-based authentication has not been enabled using the
>   db2rfe command
>   Operating system permissions of database manager files were accidentally changed
>
> **User response**
>
> Respond to this message in one of the following ways:
>
> If the instance is a non-root installed instance, enable operating system-based authentication using the db2rfe command.
>   Reset all of the operating system permissions for the database manager binary files for this instance by running the following
>   command as a superuser:
>
> ```
> db2iupdt -k <instance-name>
> ```
>
> where  is the name of the affected instance.
>
> Note that both the db2rfe command and the db2iupdt command require
>   that the database manager instance be stopped and restarted.

Are you able to connect to the database manually from some remote client (using JDBC/ODBC/CLI/DB2 CLP)?

Comment: Yes i am able to connect

Comment: Thanks, Mark for help we have restarted db2 server and db2 service it works fine.